# How to get field value from string python expression in python 3.5

Tags: python, string, expression, python-3.5, odoo-12

for example,my string python expression is:

```
res = ''
for item in object.order_line:res = res + item.product_id.name + ','result = res[:-1]
```

so i want to get the value of product_id.name while execute my python expression,

Answer (score 0):

res = res + item['product_id']['name'] + ','